# Why corrupted rc.sysinit file create syslogd error

Tags: linux, boot, systemd, init, syslogd

During boot the system hangs, and the last message while it hangs is:
Starting system logger: Can't open or create /var/run/syslogd.pid. Can't write pid.

After a while I discovered that /etc/init/rc.sysinit was corrupted - the first line was:

```
#!/bin/bsh
```

instead of:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Why that mistake resulted this result?
Why specifically this error?

Comment: Well, `rc.sysinit` performs a variety of system initialization tasks.  With a typo in the `#!` line, it wouldn't execute.  Take a look at the script, and you'll probably find that something in it is responsible for setting up `/var/run`.  For a better answer you would have to provide more information: for example, what distribution (and version) are you running?

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i understood what the problem was. I realized that since rc.sysinit didnt run properly (it did run cause it set my hostname) mtab was a read-only file, so all the mounts were read only. that is why the system falied to create the file /var/run/syslogd.pid